# Enabling depth test causes nothing at all to appear

Tags: opengl-es

I have a depth buffer and am rendering a cone on the screen. It works, but then I realized I had forgotten the standard enabling of depth testing, and when I turned it on, now nothing appears at all.

I only have this one object, a cone, in my scene, so nothing else is in front of it.

The depth buffer is setup fine:

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                              GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                              GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                              m_depthRenderbuffer);
```

The I bind the render buffer:

```
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_renderbuffer);
```

Then I render the cone:

[image]

(My experiments with this messy cone are the subject of another question I shall ask shortly).

But, as soon as I add this next line after creating the depth buffer and binding the render buffer:

`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`

...then my cone magically disappears. There is nothing, not even a little dot, on the screen.

Why would that be?

Comment: Two things I would check first: ist GL_CULL_FACE enabled? Have you tried different settings for glDepthFunc()?

Comment: glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE) is making no difference.  however, adding    glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS) made everything appear, when it followed the depth buffer enabling. I have been working off some sample code that work without this glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS) so I wonder what I'm doing that requires it?

Comment: glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS) is the same as disabling the test, so that doesn't help. Did you clear the depth buffer before rendering? glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)?

Comment: bravo, that is what I was forgetting, `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` .. make your comment an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: I had this issue, but for a different reason.  My near clipping distance was set to 0.  Turns out it needs to be positive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using **GL_DEPTH_TEST**,

**glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)** has to be called before rendering so that the depth buffer is initialized correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As fuzzyTew brought up in the comments (Apr 26, 2017), some people may have the issue where the near clipping distance was set to 0. I set this to 0.01 * cam_distance and everything was just dandy.

> [...] My near clipping distance was set to 0. Turns out it needs to be positive. – fuzzyTew Apr 26 '17 at 20:25

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and the reason was that `glDepthMask` was set to `GL_FALSE` before calling `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`.
So in addition to the above comments/answers just make sure that `glDepthMask` is set to `GL_TRUE` before clearing the depth buffer.